# ionic2 show input field when other option is selected from select box

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

Using `Ionic2` and `Angular2`, I want to give user an option to enter profession when they select option 'Other' from select box.

Example of Select:

[image]

Here is the code:

```html
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label>Select Profession</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="userType">
   <ion-option *ngFor="let ut of userTypeList" [value]="ut.value" [innerHTML]="ut.label"></ion-option>
  </ion-select>
 </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `userType` property and show the input when its value is equal to the value of the *other* option:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Select Profession</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="userType">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let ut of userTypeList" [value]="ut.value" [innerHTML]="ut.label"></ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item *ngIf="userType == 'otherOptionValue'">
  <ion-label>Detail</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)